# Why can't Pyramid locate this template file?

Tags: python, pyramid

I just installed the Pyramid framework (following the [tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html). I created a new project starting with the "alchemy" scafffold (pcreate -s alchemy myproject) and ran the setup.py script. For some reason, when I run pserve, I get a TopLevelLookupException, stating that it can't locate the template for uri 'pyramid_debugtoolbar:templates/exception_summary.dbtmako':

```
TopLevelLookupException: Can not locate template for uri 'pyramid_debugtoolbar:templates/exception_summary.dbtmako'
```

The file 'mytemplate.pt' is in the directory, but for some reason I still get this error.

Here is **init**.py:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from .models import (
    DBSession,
    Base,
    )


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Here is the views.py:

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config

from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError

from .models import (
DBSession,
MyModel,
)


@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='/templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
    try:
        one = DBSession.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.name == 'one').first()
    except DBAPIError:
        return Response(conn_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status_int=500)
    return {'one': one, 'project': 'Triumph'}

conn_err_msg = """error"""
```

here is the models.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Text,
    )

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()


class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'models'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
    value = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

Here is the development.ini file:

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:Triumph

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar

# By default, the toolbar only appears for clients from IP addresses
# '127.0.0.1' and '::1'.
# debugtoolbar.hosts = 127.0.0.1 ::1

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, triumph

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_triumph]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = triumph

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the debugtoolbar. A version was released last night on accident that did not include the required templates.

Comment: Thanks Michael, thats pretty informative. I just tried upgrading it but its still having the same issue. Currently going through the docs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official docs ([Pyramid 1.4 - Basic Layout](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html#view-declarations-via-views-py)) explaining the basic layout of a pyramid application you need to change your view configuration to this line shown below - or simply said: remove the leading slash from template path.

views.py:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
```

Temporarily disabling the pyramid debugtoolbar could help as well. Actually you have included it with one of these two ways ([docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_debugtoolbar/en/latest/#setup)). Either these settings could be fixed or you just disable it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks, but that leading forward-slash was left accidentally be me when I tried including the absolute path, since the default one apparently wasn't being found. It still doesn't work as 'templates/mytemplate.pt'.

Comment: I edited my answer to guide into another direction. Adding your development.ini to your question would help too.

Comment: Thanks alot Sascha. I commented out the debug toolbar, and it worked. Yet, I don't understand why it would do this, since I just installed Pyramid and made no changes? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting. As Michael Merickel pointed out you need to upgrade the package for pyramid_debugtoolbar to version 1.0.6 to enable it again for use in pyramid - version 1.0.5 has packaging errors. It is a really helpful tool. run this command in the virtualenv you created for pyramid (change $YOURENV to your needs): $YOURENV/bin/pip install --upgrade pyramid_debugtoolbar

Comment: Tried upgrading it; still having the same issue :/ I'm going through the docs